# NamingEnumeration hasMoreElements method takes a lot of time when returning false for LDAP

Tags: ldap

I am trying to search a LDAP server(Active Directory). When I parse the search results, the `hasMoreElements` method of `NamingEnumeration` takes around 15-20 seconds to execute when it returns false. It is not the case when it is returning true. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Code:

```
SearchControls ctrl = new SearchControls();
ctrl.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user("uid"="abc"))";
NamingEnumeration ne = dirContext.search("ldap://abc:389/dc=abc,dc=xy", searchFilter,ctrl);

if (ne != null) {
    while (ne.hasMoreElements()) {
        //parse results
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

The `NamingEnumeration` does some cleanup when calling `hasMoreElements()` the last time. It also checks if there are additional referrals is the context-property `Context.REFERRAL` is set to "follow". In one case in our software this caused exactly the behaviour as described: The last call to `hasMoreElements()` (or to `hasMore()` or calling `next()` more often than allowed) caused up to 40 seconds as referrals are searched in the LDAP context. The solution is to not set `Context.REFERRAL` to "follow".

Answer (score 0):

AD has a default limit of number of objects it returns in an LDAP query. I think it is in the 1000 object range.

If you hit 1001, you get 1000 returned, then an error, so I could see this being the case.

Count how many objects you get back in a test, and betcha you beat 1000 and then fail.